# How to decrease brightness on image using TrackBar?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can only increase the brightness using the track bar. Even if I pull it to backward the brightness keep getting increasing.

Anyone can help?

```
Bitmap newbitmap;
private void brightnessBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  brightnessLabel.Text = brightnessBar.Value.ToString();
  newbitmap = (Bitmap)boxPic.Image;
  boxPic.Image = AdjustBrightness(newbitmap, brightnessBar.Value);
}

public static Bitmap AdjustBrightness(Bitmap Image, int Value)
{
  Bitmap TempBitmap = Image;
  float FinalValue = (float)Value / 255.0f;
  Bitmap NewBitmap = new Bitmap(TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height);
  Graphics NewGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(NewBitmap);
  float[][] FloatColorMatrix ={
    new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    new float[] {FinalValue, FinalValue, FinalValue, 1, 1}
  };
  ColorMatrix NewColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(FloatColorMatrix);
  ImageAttributes Attributes = new ImageAttributes();
  Attributes.SetColorMatrix(NewColorMatrix);
  NewGraphics.DrawImage(TempBitmap,
    new Rectangle(0, 0, TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height),
    0, 0, TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height,GraphicsUnit.Pixel, Attributes);
  Attributes.Dispose();
  NewGraphics.Dispose();
  return NewBitmap;
}
```

Comment: I am really new to programming so.. How to do that please help me

Comment: You forgot to mention what are the Min-Max values of the TrackBar. But, you need to apply the new Brightness value to the original image. If you keep on setting the brightness to an image that has already been adjusted, you'll never be able to reset it (ie., you'll always increase it and never go back). The `W` rank is `float[] {brightness, brightness, brightness, 0, 1}`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code.  The first is that you are changing your image and replacing your original image.  So each time you make a change, it's adding on top of all your previous changes.  You will need to save your original image somewhere and use that as the foundation for your changes.

```
Bitmap origbitmap= null;

private void brightnessBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //we only capture the "original" bitmap once, at the start of the operation
  //and then we hold on to it to apply all future edits against the original
  if (origbitmap== null)
      origbitmap= (Bitmap)boxPic.Image;

  brightnessLabel.Text = brightnessBar.Value.ToString();
  boxPic.Image = AdjustBrightness(origbitmap, brightnessBar.Value);
}
```

The second issue is that you are applying your changes to the 'W' component of the ColorMatrix.  The documentation on the ColorMatrix is not that great (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix?view=netframework-4.7.2)

However, the W component appears to be a translation, meaning it is a straight additive to your color channels.  So the result of your operation is R = R + W, G = G + W, B = B + W, A = A + W.  What you want is, probably, a scalar operation;

```
float[][] FloatColorMatrix ={
    new float[] {FinalValue, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    new float[] {0, FinalValue, 0, 0, 0},
    new float[] {0, 0, FinalValue, 0, 0},
    new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
  };
```

`FinalValue` (from your trackbar) is a multiplier against the original color.  This isn't going to technically be a true "Brightness" adjustment (you'll want to look into color space transforms for that) but it will be a very simple way of linearly changing the intensity of each color channel.

BTW, if your trackbar is limited to 255, your FinalValue will never exceed 1 and your image will never increase in brightness.  If your trackbar goes up to 512, FinalValue could go to 2x (with the middle at 1x) so you could max out at 2x intensity per channel.

Comment: You're adjusting the contrast here, not the brigtness. Scale the trackbar value in the range `[0-100]` to a value of `[0.0f-1.0f]`, using the `W` rank. The main point is, you need to apply the brightness to **original** bitmap, not to the one that has already been adjusted.

Comment: There seems to be some debate regarding the use of W vs the use of scaling.  I found these links in support of scaling: http://www.graficaobscura.com/matrix/index.html, http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/10/use-an-imageattributes-object-to-adjust-an-images-brightness-in-c/  vs this link in support of W: http://www.gutgames.com/post/Adjusting-Brightness-of-an-Image-in-C.aspx.  I can't claim to be an image transform expert so I would recommend trying both to see what result you prefer.

Comment: It's not a matter of preference, this is what it is. There's catch (something you can test using Photoshop or similar program, all have a tool to modify the Brightness & Contrast of an image). Modifying the Brightness, the image loses quality and details fast. On the other hand, adjusting the Contrast is a less lossy procedure: the color, if scaled correctly, preserve the image original definition better. This is why, sometime, if you just care for the result, you scale the color components instead of the brightness component. I wasn't referring to quality, though.